# Turning on output buffering in a wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, hooks, session

My wordpress plugin uses sessions for handling various things, and on the production site I'm testing it on output buffering is not on by default so I'm getting a lot of messages such as these:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: 
Cannot send session cookie - 
headers already sent by 
(output started at /blah/wp-content/themes/Starkers/header.php:12) 
in /blah/wp-content/plugins/rsq/store.php on line 4
```

Is there a hook or something I can latch on to in order to turn on output buffering? Am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: yes you are. Try to find out the actual problem and why the plugin sets cookies after headers have been sent

Answer (score 2):

Although I realise this is probably not the right way to go about it, I managed to turn on output buffering using the following code in my plugin:

```
add_action('init', 'rsq_buffering');
function rsq_buffering()
{
    ob_start();
}
```

I probably should be doing any session stuff from within the init hook instead of just all over the place.